# Is there a limit to the number of nodes in a Rule Chain?

Tags: thingsboard

I am producing a rule chain that is working successfully but then suddenly it stops processing after a certain number of nodes. If I look at node A it has a success debug events but then node B following it has no events at all.

If I remove a previous node in the chain, then the processing gets to node B but not to node C. It's basically as if there is a node limit.

I am using thingsboard cloud. Anyone know of this limit?

Comment: actually I think I answered my own question here: https://thingsboard.io/products/paas/subscription/

Comment: There is no such limit for self-hosted ThingsBoard instances. Only the count of devices/assets is limited by the license you subscribed to.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is any processing throttling with the cloud version. I'm seeing it taking 2-3 seconds to go through the rule chain.

Comment: I haven't used the cloud version, yet. Only the self-hosted ThingsBoard versions. Maybe this behaviour is related to the rate limits of the cloud version (see the url you posted above).